# Sequence of funtions question.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Kind of an odd one in my book.

The question is;
show that the Series $\sum_{1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{x^{2}-n^{2}}$ converges uniformly on any compact interval that does not contain a nonzero integer, and conclude that the sum of the series is a continuous function of $\mathbb {R} \setminus \{ \pm 1, \pm 2,..\}$
i kinda understand the last bit as long as x isnt an integer removes an integer from it will always lead one uniformly to 0 ( i think anyway) but how do you prove something like this?

Comment: Can you show the result to be true on just a closed interval contained in $(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $f_n\colon x\mapsto\frac{1}{x^2-n^2}$, for $n\geq 1$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}^\ast$.

Fix any interval $[a,b]$ with $[a,b]\cap\mathbb{N}=\emptyset$.

- First, $f_n$ is well-defined on $[a,b]$ for all $n\geq 1$
- For all $x\in[a,b]$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{m} f_n(x)$ converges. Let $f$ be its limit. (pointwise convergence)
- For $N>1$,
  $$
  \begin{align*}
   R_n(x)&\stackrel{def}{=}\left|f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{N} f_n(x)\right|=\left|\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} f_n(x)\right| \leq \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \left|f_n(x)\right| \\
  &\leq \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\min(|n^2-b^2|,|n^2-a^2|)}
  \end{align*}
  $$
  for all $x\in[a,b]$; so
  $$
   \sup_{x\in[a,b]}R_n(x)\leq \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\min(|n^2-b^2|,|n^2-a^2|)} \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} 0
  $$

(You can also show normal convergence on $[a,b]$, instead of uniform.)